# How to change size of plupload thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm using **plupload plugin** to let user drag and drop images in `input[file]`. Default thumbnail size is 100x60. How can i change this size to another? My init code is:

```
$("#uploader1").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url : '../upload.php',
    max_file_count: 1,
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    filters : {
      // Maximum file size
      max_file_size : '1000mb',
      // Specify what files to browse for
      mime_types: [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
      ]
    },

    sortable: false,
    dragdrop: true,
    views: {
      list: true,
      thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
      active: 'thumbs'
    },


    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '../../js/Moxie.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '../../js/Moxie.xap'
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This widget has the `thumb_width` and `thumb_height` options to customize the thumbnail size. Check out [Allow users to make thumbnails larger in the UI Widget](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1031).

```
$("#uploader1").plupload({
    // Your settings
    thumb_width: 200,
    thumb_height: 120 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it created another problem. Now instead of loading image, it loads dummy. Maybe you know what can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Works fine for me in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQYWBP?editors=0010. See https://monosnap.com/file/64TiuYiRL7JDrt49dvkaUcQ287abIu. Check if you don't have errors in the browser console (F12). If not, modify my sample to reproduce the issue.  Also check if all images reproduce the issue.

Comment: It works fine when i'm turning css off. This is super weird. I guess i should check all "display:none" or whatever that i assigned to different elements to style plugin the way i want